# How can I make Turkey the default country when choosing a country code for a phone number?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

This script allows me to pick country code when I want to write my number:

```
const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#inpMobilePhone");
const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
    utilsScript:
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });
}
```

This html is my phone input and the reason `type=number` because when I change that to `type=tel` it's allows me to write text to:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" style="width:168%" 
        class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="@localizer["MobilePhone"]" 
        id="inpMobilePhone" name="MobilePhone" required />
</div>
```

This is the first thing i saw i want to change this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the initial country selection by specifying its country code.

```
const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
    initialCountry: "TR",
    utilsScript:
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `initialCountry` option from the documentation of intel-tel-input library.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input, about half way down the page.